# Change UserDefaults bool value when deleting app

Tags: swift

I have a `UserDefaults` bool value which tell me when I have to present my Walkthrough at the first installation of the app.When I install it, my bool value for key "firstAccessToApp" change from true to false, but if I remove the app from my device and I reinstall it, my walkthrough doesn't appear because the bool value is still false.How can I change the value when I remove my app from the device?This is my code:

```
if !defaults.bool(forKey: "firstAccessToApp") {
        present(Walkthrough(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "firstAccessToApp")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install an app, the key doesn't exist in the UserDefaults and if you try to access it, it will return the default value, which is `false`. To set it to `true` when you first install and open the app, you can add this code to your `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool` method:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

if (!defaults.dictionaryRepresentation().keys.contains("firstAccessToApp")) {
    defaults.set(true, forKey: "firstAccessToApp")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```